# Do I have to correct for multiple testing?

Tags: regression, multiple-comparisons

I am unsure whether I have to correct for multiple testing in my case. I have symptom severity ratings for several (9) symptoms across 3 time points (pre, during, post). I want to test whether "during" predicts "post" over and above "pre". So I´m comparing regression models. I do that for each symptom separately. Since I have several separate regressions that share neither IV nor DV, do I have to correct for anything?
I hope you can help me!

Comment: Multiple testing when the null hypotheses are true increases the probability of (at least once) erroneously rejecting a null hypotheses.  If spuriously producing "statistically significant" results is a concern then you should adjust for this.

Comment: Related: https://xkcd.com/882/ and http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/200640/2958

Answer (score 0):

Partially answered in comments:

> Multiple testing when the null hypotheses are true increases the
>   probability of (at least once) erroneously rejecting a null
>   hypotheses. If spuriously producing "statistically significant"
>   results is a concern then you should adjust for this.

– Henry